# What's wrong with that strings for php8 (wordpress plugin)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, php-8

I use Hyyan Polylang for Woocommerce for ages, it's old but I love it.
When I switched php version on my hosting from 7.4 to 8 and 8.1, the variable product crushes - no button, no some widgets,etc. With simple product all is fine.
The debugger showed that on the buttons place

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: NumberFormatter::format(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given in /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-poly-integration/src/Hyyan/WPI/LocaleNumbers.php:97 Stack trace: #0 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-poly-integration/src/Hyyan/WPI/LocaleNumbers.php(97): NumberFormatter->format('', 3) #1 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Hyyan\WPI\LocaleNumbers->getLocalizedDecimal('', '') #2 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php(358): apply_filters('woocommerce_for...', '', '') #4 [internal function]: wc_format_localized_decimal('') #5 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php(1330): array_map('wc_format_local...', Array) #6 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(370): wc_format_dimensions(Array) #7 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(312): WC_Product_Variable->get_available_variation(Object(WC_Product_Variation)) #8 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1749): WC_Product_Variable->get_available_variations() #9 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart('') #10 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #11 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #12 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1697): do_action('woocommerce_var...') #13 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart('') #14 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #15 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #16 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php(60): do_action('woocommerce_sin...') #17 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(785): require('/home/t80469/pu...') #18 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(284): load_template('/home/t80469/pu...', false) #19 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php(37): wc_get_template_part('content', 'single-product') #20 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/t80469/pu...') #21 /home/t80469/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/t80469/pu...') #22 /home/t80469/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/t80469/pu...') #23 {main} thrown in /home/t80469/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woo-poly-integration/src/Hyyan/WPI/LocaleNumbers.php on line 97
```

I went to /plugins/woo-poly-integration/src/Hyyan/WPI/LocaleNumbers.php, experemented where is the root of the problem, found one string

```
 //WooCommerce 3.1 unreleased checkin https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/15628
            //add_filter('woocommerce_format_localized_decimal', array($this, 'getLocalizedDecimal'), 10, 2);
```

and commented it. The lower one was commented by author, not by me.The full context is

```
    /**
     * Hook relevant WooCommerce filters to apply localisation according to Polylang locale.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (
                class_exists('\NumberFormatter') &&
                'on' === Settings::getOption('localenumbers', Features::getID(), 'on')
        ) {

            //localise standard price formatting arguments
            add_filter('wc_get_price_decimal_separator', array($this, 'getLocaleDecimalSeparator'), 10, 1);
            add_filter('wc_get_price_thousand_separator', array($this, 'getLocaleThousandSeparator'), 10, 1);
           add_filter('wc_price_args', array($this, 'filterPriceArgs'), 10, 1);

            //WooCommerce 3.1 unreleased checkin https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/15628
            //add_filter('woocommerce_format_localized_decimal', array($this, 'getLocalizedDecimal'), 10, 2);
            //no additional override on finished price format as no currency paramber available
            //add_filter('woocommerce_format_localized_price', array($this, 'getLocalizedPrice'), 10, 2);
        }
    }
```

Now debug doesn't show issues and the button works fine(I hope), but how important is that function? I want to understand,cause the plugin is important to me - it's almost in all my works.IN php 8+ is something new with number formats? Cause "NumberFormatter::format()" is in debugger. Where is that format in wordpress and how to replace it?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a WP problem. It's PHP8 standards. The problem is the plugin's methods `getLocalizedDecimal` or `getLocalizedPrice` is not passing a number to the WC filter `woocommerce_format_localized_decimal` and `woocommerce_format_localized_price`. How you fix it - find those plugin methods and make sure they are returning an `int` or `float`. Since you didn't post the plugin methods, I'm only guessing, but you can typecast the return value by adding `(int)` before the returned variable like `return (int)$variable`.

Comment: I searched getLocalizedDecimal and getLocalizedPrice with code editor, and they are only in that file of a plugin, that I posted. So they can be simply somewhere in woocommerce?

Comment: Those functions are **only** in the plugin. That's the problem. The plugin needs to be updated. The plugin is using `add_filter` to pass data to two WooCommerce hooks. Those hooks are expecting specific data types the plugin is not passing and due to PHP8, that will now throw an error. Plus, you do not want to, under any circumstance, edit WooCommerce code.

Comment: on the other place I've got the answer and I'll post it. in string 97 replace $retval = $a->format($input, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE); to $retval = $a->format((float) $input, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);, maybe someone needs it too

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what my first comment was. The value needed to be typecast to an `int` or `float`. Glad you got it working!

Comment: The best practice is to contact plugin author to update it. And since you have the fix you can share it with them to make it faster for them.